# jQuery add text from a <textarea> to <tr>

Tags: jquery, append

I've checked some similar threads, but either they were unclear or too advanced for as I'm still couple of days learning jQuery.

I have a text area:

```
<textarea class='text' rows='10' cols='25'></textarea>
```

And I want that after the user has entered some text they would press the `Add text` button

```
<button type='button' class='addText'>Add text</button>
```

and so, the text they've entered would show up in the table `<tr></tr>`.

I Googled that you can do that with jQuery append function, but didn't really get the solution to my problem.

So, is there a way to do something like this?

```
$('.addText').click(function(){
    $('.smth').append(   TEXT in TEXTAREA to TR  );
});
```

P.S.
.smth is the row class = `<tr class='smth'></tr>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a `textarea`'s value, you could use `$("#idOfTextArea").val()`, e.g.

```
var text = $("#idOfTextArea");        // run your DOM lookups once if possible
var row = $('.smth');                 // and store results in variables
row.append("<td>"+text.val()+"</td>") // add a <td> to the <tr>, with the text
```

Comment: @RnD: Or when using the class as your textarea had no id it would be similar to `$("textarea.text")` but giving it an id off course is better if you got more textareas on the page, specially if they are several siblings.

Comment: @egasimus: +1 for adding `td` ensuring valid Html, however, adding a `td` with each click seems weird. That's for OP to sort out though :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - You're right, indeed - adding a `<tr><td>text</td></tr>` to the table would make more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

API: http://api.jquery.com/val/

**code**

```
$('.addText').click(function(){
    $('.smth').append($('textarea').val()); // or $('.smth').append($('.text').val());
});
```

Comment: This appends a textarea to the table, which isn't what OP needs as far as I understand.

Comment: How to append the text in the textarea to the table.

Comment: @Tats_innit: As a side-note: I know OP asked pretty much for adding the text to `tr` with class `smth` but adding text to a `tr` is invalid Html. According to  http://validator.w3.org it causes validation error "Misplaced non-space characters insided a table."